# Ways to translate and read Chinese patent in English

Tags: language, chinese-patent

I wish to read Chinese patent and does not know how to read Chinese language.

- What should i do to get that patent in English version ?
- How to translate Chinese Patent?
- What will be the authenticity of such translation?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to get translated version of Chinese patent some of them are listed below:-

1. [PAID WAY] Get a  certified translator service; (certified copy can be obtained from person and will be accepted in front of non-Chinese authorities)
2. [FREE WAY 1] (via - Chinese Patent Office); (using - machine translation):

..

- Visit [chinese patent office official site](http://english.sipo.gov.cn/)
- locate patent search tab
- input your search term; eg patent number
- Click on relevant result
- Locate a button called **Machine Translation** at bottom of page.
- Navigate using 'First, Prev, Next, Last' hyper link in page

[image]

3. [FREE WAY 2] via- Espacenet

   - Search and find patent using Espacenet service;
   - Go to description tab
   - use Pattranslate button to get english version
     [image]
4. Most of the Time a person can get English version of the translation using above 2 free methods. but in case no translation can be achieved then you have to download PDF version of the patent. Get a OCR run on that PDF file. Software to use in such case is to be Acrobat Professional prefrably above 9 Pro version. After successful OCR use Google translate to get english version of text.

Answer (score 2):

You may try using a patent database provided by Chinese vendoer named [incoPat](https://www.incopat.com/).
incoPat not only provides English interface but translates Chinese patents' biblio data and full-text into English. Chinese patents can be read and searched by English.
Furthermore, patent related data like Chinese patent litigation, assignment, licensing information are all translated into English which can be read and searched by English.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Although this is a commerical database, you can apply for a free trial through the website to have a short term using the database freely to search and download the patents you need.

Comment: Do they translate the patents themselves / have a translation engine or is the translation the same as in google patents or espacenet?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for the Chinese patent number in http://gpsn.uspto.gov/ for an English translation , or I believe the chinese website SIPO has english translations of their patents.  Also you can check to see http://www.epo.org/searching/asian/china/faq.html for how to navigate the chinese patent database websites and maybe extract the spec in chinese and run that through google translate.

Comment: All of the patents from China that see displayed at google/patents are machine translated. Are you sure you are looking in google/patents?